# Doubtful solution to an exercise on faithful flatness in Matsumura's Commutative Algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, proof-verification, tensor-products

The exercise on page 30. It says that:

> Let $A, B$ be integral domain having the same field of fractions, $B \supseteq A$. Prove that $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$ only when $B = A$.

My solution seems to be easy, which makes me doubt its correctness. My idea is to prove that for any $x \in B$, $x \in A$ so that $B \subseteq A$. By assumption that $A, B$ have the same field of fraction, any element of $B$ is of the form $a/b$ for $a, b \in A$, $b \not= 0$. By faithful flatness, the sequence of $A$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow A[X]/(bX - a) \rightarrow 0$$
is exact if and only if the sequence of $B$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow \underbrace{A \otimes_A B}_{B} \rightarrow A[X]/(bX - a) \otimes_A B \rightarrow 0$$
is exact. We have
\begin{align*}
A[X]/(bX - a) \otimes_A B &\cong A[X]/(bX - a) \otimes_{A[X]} A[X] \otimes_A B\\
&\cong A[X]/(bX - a) \otimes_{A[X]} B[X]\\
&\cong B[X]/(bX - a)\\
&\cong B &\text{ because }a/b \in B
\end{align*}
So the second sequence is exact: $0 \rightarrow B \rightarrow B \rightarrow 0$. This implies the first sequence is exact and that can only occurs when $a/b \in A$.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is fatal flaw towards the end of your proof when you say $B[X]/(bX - a) \cong B$ because $a/b \in B$.

For example, let $A$ be a domain and $a \in A$.  Then $a^2 / a = a \in A$ but $A[X]/(aX - a^2)$ is not even a domain, so clearly is not isomorphic to $A$.

A correct solution might look like:

Let $A \subseteq B$ and $a/b \in B$.  Then $(b :_A a) = (b :_A a)B \cap A = (bB :_A aB) \cap A = B \cap A = A$.  The first equality uses that $I = IB \cap A$ for all $A$-ideals under faithfully flat extension.  The second equality is a fundamental property of colon ideals under flat extensions.  So $a = bc$ for some $c \in A$, i.e. $a/b \in A$.