# $K(X)$ is not faithfully flat $K[X]$ module.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, tensor-products, flatness

How can I show that for a field $K,$  $K(X)$ is not faithfully flat as $K[X]$ module.

$K(X)$ is a localization of $K[X],$ it is flat $K[X]$ module. But I cannot prove that tensor by $K(X)$ is not a faithful functor. I need some help.

Comment: My intuition: since the extension of the maximal ideal $(X)$ of $K[X]$ in $K(X)$ is exactly $K(X),$ it is not faithfully flat.

Comment: Unless an integral domain is a field, its field of fractions is never faithfully (flat). (Recall that a flat morphism $R\to S$ is faithfully flat iff $IS\cap R=I$ for every ideal $I\subset R$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More generally,  if $R \subset S$ is an extension of integral domains having the same field of fractions and if $S$ is faithfully flat over $R$, then $R=S$.

For a domain $D$ that is not a field, this shows that the field of fractions of $D$ is never faithfully flat over $D$.

A proof of this fact, which appears as an exercise in Matsumura, is [found here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486841/doubtful-solution-to-an-exercise-on-faithful-flatness-in-matsumuras-commutative)